# Simulation tool for Spectrum Sensing in Cognitive Radio

Tags: simulation

What is the best tool for SS in CR that we can implement algorithms to see graphical result ?

Either by programming or drag&drop tools. Some I heard are Omnet++, Opnet, ns-2 (unix), Matlab. But I'm looking for lower level implementing, and less coding.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

MATLAB seems good to implement CRNs.
You can also see NS2, NS3, Omnet++.

I personally prefer Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

The better tool for graphical result is MATLAB, you can also use Network Simulator-2 but it may provide you the pictorial view of node like that.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab will be a good choice for implementing algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend NetSim from Tetcos for 802.22 cognitive radio simulation. You could see the following for more information

https://tetcos.com/cognitive-radio.html
https://tetcos.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/14000045189-how-is-spectrum-sensing-done-in-netsim-802-22-library-